# possible ways to write a positive integer n as a sum of k positive integers(without order) such that there is no repetition of any integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What are the possible ways to write a positive integer n as a sum of k positive integers(without order)   such that there is no repetition of any integer?

I came across this [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) but it allows repetition of integers.

For example, I can write 4 as 7 as 4+2+1 but not as 3 +2 +2 (due to repetition)
Note: In this case 7=4+2+1 and 7=4+1+2 are same and I require a list of the possible ways.

Comment: These are called strict partitions. Are you looking for a way to count them or to find them all?

Comment: i believe that's already listed at OEIS

Comment: please check up my `NON ADDITIVE-SUBTRACTIVE PRIME SEQUENCE`.there you will find a very interesting/nice prime sequence.

Comment: @MattSamuel: I am looking for finding them all i.e not only no. of ways but also the list of ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a bivariate generating function. The coefficient of $x^n$ in
$$ \prod_{r=1}^{+\infty}(1+x^r) $$
gives the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of distinct positive numbers, hence if we consider:
$$ \prod_{r=1}^{+\infty}(1+y x^r)=f_0(x)+y\,f_1(x)+y^2\,f_2(x)+\ldots$$
we are just looking for the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f_k(x)$, or:
$$ [x^n][y^k]\prod_{r=1}^{+\infty}(1+y x^r).$$